# Stop testing after specific failures

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I have unpredictable behavior page that depends on changes that create developers. And sometimes my tests failed, because page wasn't load. My test scenario structure looks like:

```
describe('0. first actions', function () {
    var lib = require("../../common.js");
    var config = browser.params;
    var url = config.listOfReferencesUrl, toolbar;

    load(url, "list-of-references");

    beforeAll(function () {
        // some actions on the page
    });

    it('test0', function () {
        since('test0 failed').
            expect(toolbar.isPresent()).toBe(true);
    });

    describe('1.actions1', function () {

    beforeAll(function () {
        // some actions on the page
    });

    it('test1', function () {
        since('test1 failed').       
            expect(table.getRow(clientNameNum).getRowInput().isEnabled()).toBe(true);
    });

    // ... another invested describes 
});
```

Where load function is:

```
global.load = function (url, pageType) {
  browser.get(url);
  if (pageType == 'list-of-references'){
    browser.executeScript("icms.go('WEB_INQ_PROC', 'InquiryList', null, 0)");
  }
  browser.waitForAngular();
};
```

I wonder if I can create structure to stop my tests if page isn't load. But I don't want to use `'jasmine-bail-fast'`, because I want to see another failures if page will load.
I tried to write something like:

```
if (this.results_.failedCount > 0) {
    // Hack: Quit by filtering upcoming tests
    this.env.specFilter = function(spec) {
        return false;
    };
}
```

But it isn't working. I use jasmine2.
Maybe somebody know how I can organize it?

Comment: What is the value of `load` function when page fail or succeed to load ? Did it return a boolean, a promise, an HTML element ?

Comment: @Freezystem I updated my question and added load-function description. It just run script and waiting for angular.

Comment: Unless you're loading an external library I think `beforeAll()` didn't actually exists in Jasmine core. Have you tried to load your page within a `beforeEach()` block ?

Comment: @Freezystem it exist in Jasmine2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32249393/isolation-of-actions-and-tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a wrapper

```
var filter = function (fn) {
  if (!condition)
    throw new Error('skipped');

  return fn;
}
```

and use it on all relevant `describe`/`it` blocks:

```
describe('...', filter(function () {
  ...
}));
```

Comment: @ estusThanks! But I have an error: "ReferenceError: filter is not defined". Where I can see some examples of using it?

Comment: You need to have it defined in your specs. `require` `filter` function or define it as `window.filter` (similar to how angular-mock [defines its globals](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock#function)). I think it is more straightforward and clean approach than hijacking `env.specFilter`.